# Image loading: JavaScript onLoad and Image::complete (FireFox 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox3.6, onload-event

When loading images into a JavaScript `Image` object, I would presume that, once the `load` event is triggered for an image `i`, then `i.complete` should be `true`. Either that is not happening or (more likely, I suspect) I have a bug in my jQuery/JavaScript code.

The code (stripped way down, but I'm quite confident that what is relevant is here)

```
$img = $('<img />');  // This line added by edit for clarification
var eventData = {
        sheet: this,
        resolution: resolution,
        i: i,
    };

$img.bind('load', eventData, onTileLoad);
$img.attr('src', tile.src);

onTileLoad = function(ev) {
    var sheet = ev.data.sheet;
    var resolution = ev.data.resolution;
    var i = ev.data.i;

    if (!this.complete) {
        console.log('Image load not complete: sheet ' + sheet.sheetName + 
                ', resolution ' + resolution + ' tile ' + i)
    };

    ....
};
```

This console log triggers for some, but by no means most, of my images. I would think it should never trigger. For what it's worth, I'm working in FireFox 3.6.18 (because it is very stable and has good developer tools).

Anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

What `$img` refers to ?

<strike>In the `onTileLoad` function, `this` refers to `$img`. If `$img` is a jQuery object (as it looks like), it has no `complete` property. The `complete` property is set on the DOM object only.</strike>

Look at this [`test case`](http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/8Cuaw/).

Hope this will help,

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, ahead of all this `var $img = $('<img />');`. Now Edited accordingly.

Comment: But in `onTileLoad`, `this` won't be `$img`, it will be the JavaScript `Image` object. That's how `this` works in an event handler. If I wanted a jQuery object, I'd have to user `$(this)`. So `complete` should be set on the correct object and, indeed, most of the time it is: as I said above, "This console log triggers for some, but by no means most, of my images."

Comment: yes.. you're right, forget what I've said ^^ I still search where's the problem =)

Comment: it's seems to work.. http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/8Cuaw/5/ maybe try it with you own url ? I've no more idea where the problem could came from

Comment: Again: it usually works. The issue is that it doesn't *always* work. The question is, what is going on when it *doesn't* work. If you don't have any idea, fine, but perhaps someone will.